# add dynamic click on checkbox and to get inputName in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic `input` which will have `checkbox` to hide the inputs when you tick the `checkbox`, at the moment I'm trying to add `click="getChk()` to the `checkbox` however it was only giving me the last `index` inputName.

Say I have input Ids (code, sku, id).

My dynamic inputs and checks code line is

```
for (var x = 0; x < searchParams.length; x++) {
     var container = $('#checkBox');
     var inputs = container.find('input');
     var id = inputs.length + 1;
     var inputName = searchParams[x].name;
     $('<textarea />', { id: inputName, name: inputName, placeholder: inputName, rows: "2", class: "search-area-txt col-sm-12" }).appendTo(searchbox);
     $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'x' + id, name: inputName }).appendTo(checkBox);
     $('<label />', { 'for': 'x' + id, text: inputName, id: inputName, name: inputName }).appendTo(checkBox);
}
```

But this will need to be saved in the `localStorage` so when refresh it will persist the input to be hidden when its exists in the `localStorage`.

***Edit***: the code below should save the name in the `localStorage` in array form.

```
var inputNames = [];
getChk(id){
 var indexOfItem = inputNames.indexOf(name)
 if (indexOfItem >= 0) {
    inputNames.splice(indexOfItem, 1);
 } else {
    inputNames.push(name);
 }
 localStorage.setItem('chked', JSON.stringify(inputNames))
}
```

My attempt is by adding `.click(function(){})`

```
$('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'x' + id, name: inputName }).appendTo(checkBox).click(function(){
 getChk(id); // only gives me the id name
});
```

HTML inputs and checkbox html
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because when the `click` event handler runs the `for` loop has completed, therefore the `id` variable holds the last value.

To fix this, amend your click handler to read the `id` attribute directly from the element which raised the event:

```
$('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'x' + id, name: inputName }).appendTo(checkBox).click(function() {
   getChk(this.id);
});
```

Also, as spotted by @guest271314, the correct method when setting `localStorage` data is `setItem()`, not `set()`:

```
localStorage.setItem('checked', id);
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant to say `.setItem`, oh right will try adding `this`

Comment: but how can I correspond the `checkbox` to the `textarea`, just reliased that `this.id` will only give me the `id` of the `checkbox` not the `textarea`

Comment: You could store a `data` attribute on all the grouped elements and select by that, or use DOM traversal depending on how they appear in the page.

Comment: is it possible to show how? I've added a screenshot of the html structure of the inputs/checks

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
getChk(e){
 localStorage.set('checked', this.id);
 console.log('input id>> ', this.id);
}

.click(getChk);
```